# TypeScript types to external library

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an external library without types. Looks something like that:

```
var method1 = require('./method1');
var method2 = require('./method1');

module.exports = {
   method1: method1,
   method2: method2
}
```

I created a directory "typings/lib-name"(added "typings" in typeRoots). In this folder I have index.d.ts file and there something like this:

```
declare module "lib-name" {
  import { Method1Interface, ... } from "./modules/method1.d.ts";
  import { Method2Interface, ... } from "./modules/method2.d.ts";

  export {
    Method1Interface,
    Method2Interface,
    ...
  }
}
```

And when I try to use it in my code:

```
import lib from "lib-name"

lib.method1()
```

I get: `TS2339: Property 'method1' does not exist on type 'typeof import("lib-name")'`

I just starting with TS so I would be grateful for explaining where I went wrong.

**EDITED**
I added default export in module:

```
declare module "lib-name" {
  import { Method1Interface, ... } from "./modules/method1.d.ts";
  import { Method2Interface, ... } from "./modules/method2.d.ts";

  export {
    Method1Interface,
    Method2Interface,
    ...
  }

  default export {
   method1: Method1Interface 
  }
}
```

But then method1 has type any. I don't understand why.

**EDITED2**
It works when I defined methods before default export.

```
declare module "lib-name" {
  import { Method1Interface, ... } from "./modules/method1.d.ts";
  import { Method2Interface, ... } from "./modules/method2.d.ts";

  const method1: Method1Interface;
  const method2: Method2Interface;

  export {
    Method1Interface,
    Method2Interface,
    ...
  }

  default export {
   method1,
   method2
  }
}
```

Comment: You use `import lib from "lib-name"` but I don't see any `export default` in your `index.d.ts`

Comment: You right but When I add

`export default { method1: Method1Interface }`

Then method1 has type "any" I don't understand  O>O

Comment: Show `Method1Interface` definition

Comment: It works when I defined methods before default export (see my edit2). I suppose I can't use `method1: Method1Interface` syntax in export. Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. Firstly I didn't have a default export. Next, default export shouldn't use syntax like this:

```
default export {
  method1: Method1Interface
}
```

I defined method1 before the default export and then all works fine.

```
declare module "lib-name" {
  import { Method1Interface, ... } from "./modules/method1.d.ts";
  import { Method2Interface, ... } from "./modules/method2.d.ts";

  const method1: Method1Interface;
  const method2: Method2Interface;

  export {
    Method1Interface,
    Method2Interface,
    ...
  }

  default export {
   method1,
   method2
  }
}
```

Comment: your default export {method1, method2} is not valid typescript. I get "Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)". It is not clear in your answer what is the final solution for each file separately.